# Подскажите как вытащить куки из файла

Tags: c#

Из примера: [Encrypted cookies in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532870/encrypted-cookies-in-chrome#25874366)

Хочу понять как вытащить куки из файла, в интернета нашёл очень мало информации по этому способу, может кто нибудь уже пробовал подобное поделитесь разработкой.. 
Или же вызвать метод из примера?

UP...

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов который ВОЗМОЖНО тебе подойдет -- используй селениум. Тогда ты сможешь зайти на сайт и посмотреть програмно весь список кук которые сайт тебе отправляет.

Если же ты просто пытаешься достать куки из файла -- здесь тебе вряд ли что-нибудь посоветуют. Их шифруют именно для того, что бы их было сложно украсть :) Это, ведь, способ уберечь пользователей от похищения их данных. Здесь скорее уж на хакерские форумы с этим вопросом.